# There is wolves in the forest

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I know that we say: *there/ this is a dog* but *there are dogs*, but recently I heard following sentences:

> 1. ***There is wolves in the forest*** (Game of Thrones, A Clash of Kings)

and

> 2. ***This is the Stations of the Cross*** (BBC Modern Masters 2/4 Matisse).

Shouldn’t it rather be: **There are wolves in the forest**. Is this a kind of stylistic treatment of showing different ways of people talking? This was a sentence said by one of the brothers of the Night’s watch, so many of them weren’t educated. And I know that variety of styles is used in the book.

I probably wouldn’t bother at all with this construction if it hadn’t been for the second sentence which is said by highly educated, well-known BBC presenter.

I don’t think so that in his case it is a kind of stylistic treatment. Is the phrase ***the Stations of the Cross*** treated as something singular? Can we also say This are the Stations of the Cross?

---

So to sum up:
Is it correct to say ***There is wolves in the forest***?

Which one is better to say: ***This is the Station of the Cross*** or ***This are the Stations of the Cross***? Or both are OK? Or only the first one?

Comment: #2 seems to take "Stations of the Cross" as a title. Since only one title is mentioned, it agrees numerically with "is". For #1, this might be an attempt to mimic a regionalism.

Comment: Don't over-think this one. [*There's eggs in the (fridge / cupboard / whatever)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22there%27s+eggs+in+the%22) gets almost 200 hits in Google Books. Note [*this ELU answer*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/140888/2637), which quotes *The Cambridge Guide to English Usage* as saying *In conversation the combination of **there’s** with a plural noun is in fact more common than **there are**, according to the 'Longman Grammar'*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There **is** wolves in the forest

*Game of Thrones* may be using a *dialectic*/*stylized* speech where

> I'm going to get *them* wolves.

might also be used.

> This **is** the Stations of the Cross.

may be referring to the stations as a single group, since they usually are presented as a group in a specific section of a church (would have to see the broadcast to know the context).

> These **are** the Stations of the Cross.

refers to the 14 or so individual stations.